# Does Python uses Memory Pooling for Strings, Integers

Tags: python

I have written simple Python code

```
#For String Types
d_new = dict(a_str="captainmarvel", b_str="captainmarvel", c_str="captainmarvel", d_str="captainmarvel")
print(id(d_new['a_str']))
p_str = "captainmarvel"
print(id(p_str))

#For int types
d = dict(a=4, b=4, c=4, d=4)
print(id(d['a']))
p = 4
print(id(p))
```

it returns output as

```
270985349584
270985349584
1559653536
1559653536
```

which are same object ids for integer value 4 and string value `"captainmarvel"`. So does python reuses/pools its basic data types e.g. `int, string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPython implementation occasionally does this for immutable objects, yes. (Other implementations like PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc. might not.)

When exactly it does it is an implementation detail; most of the time you don't really need to bother with object `id`entity.